# puppet facts on centos fails but works in ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, puppet, centos7, puppet-enterprise, fact

I got following error while running below puppet module. I have 2 agents one is ubuntu 18.04 and centos7 
Below code works in ubuntu and stopping the firewall, but in centos i got below error.

> Error: Could not retrieve catalog from remote server: Error 500 on
>   SERVER: {"message":"Server Error: Evaluation Error: A substring
>   operation does not accept a String as a character index. Expected an
>   Integer (file:
>   /etc/puppetlabs/code/modules/service_disable_firewall/manifests/init.pp,
>   line: 9, column: 21) on node
>   node-01.home86.com","issue_kind":"RUNTIME_ERROR"} Warning: Not using
>   cache on failed catalog Error: Could not retrieve catalog; skipping
>   run

Line 9 is

```
case $facts['os']['family'] {
```

My code is

```
class service_disable_firewall {

  case $facts['os']['family'] {
    'Debian': {
      service { 'ufw':
      ensure => stopped,
      }
    }
    'RedHat': {
      service { 'firewalld':
      ensure => stopped,
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Issue got resolved after changing "case" as below

case $::operatingsystem {

Comment: This sounds like `$facts['os']` is resolving to a String instead of a Hash on your Centos7 system, which means either there is a bug in Facter or a problem on that system with what the Facter provider is using.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation

Comment: ... or if you're using version 3 of the Puppet agent, it could just be that fact stringification is enabled on the RedHat machine, but not on the Ubuntu machine.  This was configuration setting `stringify_facts`, and it defaulted to `true`.  It was removed in Puppet 4: in that and subsequent versions, facts are never stringified.

Comment: Hey !! you are correct, in centos it was puppet 3, i updated it to 5 and now it works
can you post this as a answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue got resolved after changing "case" as below

```
case $::operatingsystem {
```

But still not sure why did my first code fail.

Answer (score 0):

Try `${facts['os']['family']}` instead of `$facts['os']['family']`

Works for me on both

Comment: This is a syntax error for me in puppet 6.